# Line Breaks in Web Push Notifications on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

So for my app which sends out **web push notification**, I wanted to show an exact preview of how notification will look when sent out.
So I wanted to know about some rules/patterns but could not find any standard doc for the same.

- How many maximum characters does it allow in message field? (I suppose it is ~100 characters)
- How does it treat linebreaks | newlines?

I experimented out by sending few notifications but it did not follow a pattern. In some it showed only few linebreaks ~3 out of many while in some it was upto 5.

For e.g., message content for one of the notification was,

```
Exclusive Offer at Reliance Trends Aundh

Welcome to Diwali Offer ! 
At Reliance Trends
50% Off
On our exclusive
Electronics Limited Period
```

It went out like this,

[image]

Comment: Do show your sample payload.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Hi. I was kinda hoping to see your whole sample payload structure? Not just the message you include in the payload.